# Why can't I pass any url from my Jelastic manifest settings to the lets encrypt manifest?

Tags: lets-encrypt, jelastic

I am trying to do something very simple. I have a Jelastic environment with an nginx load balancer. On that balancer, I want to install the let's encrypt addon with the following manifest:

```yaml
type: update
name: load balancer

targetNodes:
  nodeGroup:
    - bl

settings:
  fields:
    - name: externalDomains
      caption: External domain names (;-separated list)
      type: string
      vtype: domainlist
      required: true

onInstall:
  - installAddon:
      id: letsencrypt

addons:
  - id: letsencrypt
    name: letsencrypt
    onInstall:
      - install [bl]:
          envName: ${env.envName}
          jps: https://github.com/jelastic-jps/lets-encrypt/blob/master/manifest.jps
          settings:
            customDomains: ${settings.externalDomains}
```

When I run that manifest, I need to provide an external domain:

[image]

Then the installation runs with success, in apparence. Then I click the addons' "Configure" button:

[image]

And I see that unfortunately the "External Domain(s)" field is empty:

[image]

That's unfortunate, because I set it to `${settings.externalDomains}`.

If I, however, install the following manifest, then everything is fine:

```yaml
type: update
name: load balancer

targetNodes:
  nodeGroup:
    - bl

onInstall:
  - installAddon:
      id: letsencrypt

addons:
  - id: letsencrypt
    name: letsencrypt
    onInstall:
      - install [bl]:
          envName: ${env.envName}
          jps: https://github.com/jelastic-jps/lets-encrypt/blob/master/manifest.jps
          settings:
            customDomains: ${env.envName}.my-provider.com
```

As long as I write anything manually in the addons' `customDomains` field, it is fine. As soon as I put there a value from the `settings`, the value gets discarded. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter that is passed to the customDomains should be passed in the add-on first:

```
onInstall:
  - installAddon:
      id: letsencrypt
      settings:
        externalDomains: ${settings.externalDomains}
```

Then it can be used in the add-on body.

The full add-on manifest:

```
type: update
name: load balancer

targetNodes:
  nodeGroup:
  - bl
settings:
  fields:
  - name: externalDomains
    caption: External domain names (;-separated list)
    type: string
    vtype: domainlist
    required: true

onInstall:
  - installAddon:
      id: letsencrypt
      settings:
        externalDomains: ${settings.externalDomains}

addons:
  - id: letsencrypt
    name: letsencrypt
    
    onInstall:
      - install:
          envName: ${env.envName}
          nodeGroup: bl
          jps: https://github.com/jelastic-jps/lets-encrypt/blob/master/manifest.jps
          settings:
            customDomains: ${settings.externalDomains}
```

JPS behavior can be checked in the console tab: -

{DOMAIN_URL}/console

The test manifest console logs:

```
[07:33:10 letsencrypt]: BEGIN INSTALLATION: letsencrypt
[07:33:11 letsencrypt]: BEGIN HANDLE EVENT: {"topic":"application/install","envAppid":"c5b959b2a936d56a23daa6964b15dc19"}
[07:33:11 letsencrypt:1]: install [bl]:  {"envName":"env-sup","nodeGroup":"bl","settings":{"customDomains":"domain8.com"}}
[07:33:11]: BEGIN MIXINS INITIALIZATION: Let's Encrypt Free SSL
[07:33:11]: loading mixin [configs/vers.yaml].response: {"result":0}
[07:33:11]: END MIXINS INITIALIZATION: Let's Encrypt Free SSL

[07:33:12 Let's.SSL]: BEGIN INSTALLATION: Let's Encrypt Free SSL
[07:33:12 Let's.SSL]: BEGIN HANDLE EVENT: {"topic":"application/install","envAppid":"c5b959b2a936d56a23daa6964b15dc19"}
[07:33:12 Let's.SSL:1]: setGlobals [bl]:  {"nodeId":"","nodeGroup":"bl","withExtIp":"true","webroot":"","webrootPath":"","fallbackToX1":"","deployHook":"","deployHookType":"","undeployHook":"","undeployHookType":"","test":""}
```

So here you can see whether parameters are passed and displayed successfully.

Comment: OMG that was a very stupid mistake. Thank you so much for the clarification.